# C# Interface EventHandler is always null

Tags: c#, interface, eventhandler

I have an interface and I want to add an event handler. But at the point where I want to invoke the event, the event handler is null.

My interface class:

```
public delegate void AddedErrorEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public interface ISynchronizationErrorRepository
{
   event AddedErrorEventHandler ErrorAdded;
   ...
}
```

My repository class which implements the interface:

```
public class EfSynchronizationErrorRepository : ISynchronizationErrorRepository
{
    public event AddedErrorEventHandler ErrorAdded;

    public void MethodToWhichCallsTheEvent(){
        ...
        ErrorAdded?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); //Here "ErrorAdded" is always null
        ...    
    }
}
```

My class to register for the event:

```
public PreveferencesViewModel(){
    IocContainer.Get<ISynchronizationErrorRepository>().ErrorAdded += NotificationErrorAdded;
}

private void NotificationErrorAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

What is the problem? I don't get it.

Comment: To expand on mjwills' comment: `EfSynchronizationErrorRepostiory` implements `ISynchronizationErrorRepostiory`, but in your IocContainer you subscribe to the `ErrorAdded` event of `ISynchronizationManager`

Comment: Sorry for the misleading question. In my code I reference to `IocContainer.Get<ISynchronizationErrorRepostiory>()`. (Copied the wrong code)
And the registration looks like this:
` IoCContract.Create<ISynchronizationErrorRepostiory, EfSynchronizationErrorRepostiory>(),`

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. And please correct the spelling of repository.

Comment: The problem is that it works in a minimal example. But not in my big project.